# Moving LUNs Previously Attached to Windows 2003 to Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage

We have LUNs from Storage Arrays ( SGI TP9700 FW 6.18 ) previously attached to Windows 2003 to be moved to a Windows 2008 R2 server.

Installing and configuring MPIO from SMIA-WSX64-10.80.30.53 my LUN become Uninitialized and unallocated..

Need your Help please..

Comment: Way more detail needed. iSCSI? FC? FCoE? MPIO? If so, which MPIO software? Where do you see the error that the lun is 'uninitialized'?

Comment: Thank you Basil, more details( 100GB volume mapped with host type Windows 2003, i see it in windows 2008 (device manager,Disk drive,SGI TP9700 Multi-Path Disk Device) The MPIO is from LSI SANtricity ES Storage Manager 10.80.x0.53

Comment: I see the Disk Uninitialized & Unallocated  When i go to Disk Management in Windows

Comment: A lot of SAN arrays need you to specify the OS of the hosts that will be attaching to any given LUN, and in my experience they always differentiate between Windows Server 2003 and lower and 2008 and higher - I don't know what that difference is but there's clearly a reason for having that 'break' in versions. Can you check on your SAN (I don't know what make/model sorry) to see if the LUNs specify the OS and consider changing it to 2008 if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

The MPIO setup in windows might be your problem. If you have a host kit from your storage vendor, ensure it's been properly installed. If you don't, then install the generic [windows MPIO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619752%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and discover the volumes through it instead of disk management.

Comment: you'll need the dsm from your san vendor also.

Comment: II failed to find the generic windows MPIO, how get this?

Comment: @tony: the MPIO/DSM used one the windows2008 is from the vendor, still my question is: how to make my lun mapped with host type windows2003 work properly on windows2008 server?

Comment: Calling the LUN "windows 2003" doesn't prevent it from being properly mounted on a 2008 server. That's host emulation, and governs some of the low level scsi behaviour, but you can absolutely mount a LUN no matter what the host emulation is set to.

Comment: @Basil: as i said the LUN is mount on windows2008 but not initialized/Unallocated i can't see my old data

Comment: Setting the emulation to 2003 doesn't prevent you from seeing data in the LUN on 2008. Or it shouldn't at any rate. You could try setting it to 2008 and see whether that fixes it. I don't think that's the problem, though.

Comment: @Basil: whast you mean by Setting the emulation to 2003?

Comment: When you select a type of operating system for a volume, you're setting the host emulation. It won't prevent other types of operating systems from reading the volume, though.